How to make Repeater item count dynamic in Laravel Filament V3?
In Laravel Filament I want to increase or decrease the numbers of repeater items on change the value in count InputText. The live() method is not reactive in this case.
TextInput::make('count')
    ->numeric()
    ->live()
    ->default(3),
Repeater::make('installments')
    ->schema([
        TextInput::make('amount')->numeric()->placeholder('Installment Amount')->hiddenLabel(),
        TextInput::make('interval')->numeric()->placeholder('Interval')->hiddenLabel(),
        Select::make('interval_unit')->hiddenLabel()->placeholder('Interval Unit'),
    ])
    ->defaultItems(function (Get $get) {
        return $get('count');
    })
    ->hiddenLabel()
    ->deletable(false)
    ->addable(false)
    ->columnSpan(3)
    ->reorderable(false)
    ->columns(3),

In the initial load it displays 3 items  as default value of count is 3 but changing the value of count in the TextInput field does not change the number of repeater items.
How do I make this repeater items dynamic?

I would do something like this:
TextInput::make('count')
    ->numeric()
    ->live()
    ->default(3)
    ->minValue(0)
    ->afterStateUpdated(function (Set $set, Get $get, ?int $state, ?int $old): void {
        if (is_null($state)) {
            $set('installments', []);
            return;
        }

        $installments = $get('installments');
        $itemsToBeAdded = $state - $old;

        if ($itemsToBeAdded > 0) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $itemsToBeAdded; $i++) {
                $installments[] = [];
            }
        } else if ($itemsToBeAdded < 0) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < abs($itemsToBeAdded); $i++) {
                array_pop($installments);
            }
        }

        $set('installments', $installments);
    }),
Repeater::make('installments')
    ->schema([
        TextInput::make('amount')->numeric()->placeholder('Installment Amount')->hiddenLabel(),
        TextInput::make('interval')->numeric()->placeholder('Interval')->hiddenLabel(),
        Select::make('interval_unit')->hiddenLabel()->placeholder('Interval Unit'),
    ])
    ->defaultItems(function (Get $get) {
        return $get('count');
    })
    ->hiddenLabel()
    ->deletable(false)
    ->addable(false)
    ->columnSpan(3)
    ->reorderable(false)
    ->columns(3),

What I changed?

I added the afterStateUpdated function, where I retrieve the current state of both count and installments (using $get) and I calculate whether we need to add or remove an item (using $set).
And last but not least, do not let the minValue of count to be less than 0 by chaining the ->minValue(0) line.

Docs:

https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/advanced#field-updates
https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/advanced#injecting-the-state-of-another-field
https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/advanced#injecting-a-function-to-set-the-state-of-another-field
https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/fields/text-input#size-validation


thanks it works. However there is an small issue, it works fine if no data has entered in the repeater items e.g. InputText (amount or interval ) ,But  If some data has entered and after that I want to increase or decrease 1 repeater item by clicking increment/decrement button of Textinput then $old value and $state becomes same (I don't know why). So no increase or decrease the repeater items. It starts increasing or decreasing only after 1 more increment/decrement in the count Textinput.
